# Using a definition to produce an specific example of a locale in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm working on a theory that requires usage of rings, so I imported the following theories: https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/devel/AFP/Group-Ring-Module/

Right now, I have defined a set X of a certain type and I'd like to define operations on it to make it a ring, as in the locale "Ring" of the imported theory.

How do I define a ring with carrier X and have it recognized as an instance of the locale "Ring"?

The locale "Ring" is declared by extending "aGroup", which in turn is declared by extending "Group", which is in the theory "Algebra2.thy":

```
record 'a Group = "'a carrier" + 
  top      :: "['a, 'a ] ⇒ 'a" (infixl "⋅ı" 70)
  iop      :: "'a  ⇒  'a" ("ρı _" [81] 80)
  one     :: "'a"   ("ı") 

locale Group =
 fixes G (structure)
 assumes top_closed: "top G ∈ carrier G → carrier G → carrier G"
 and     tassoc : "⟦a ∈ carrier G; b ∈ carrier G; c ∈ carrier G⟧ ⟹
         (a ⋅ b) ⋅ c = a ⋅ (b ⋅ c)"
 and     iop_closed:"iop G ∈ carrier G → carrier G"
 and     l_i :"a ∈ carrier G ⟹  (ρ a) ⋅ a = "
 and     unit_closed: " ∈ carrier G"
 and     l_unit:"a ∈ carrier G ⟹  ⋅ a = a"
```

Another possible problem I antecipate: if I'm not mistaken, the carrier must be of type 'a set, but my set X is of type ('a set \times 'a) set set. Is there a workaround?

EDIT: In order to better formulate the sequential question in the comments, here are some pieces of what I did. All that follows is within the context of a locale *presheaf*, that fixes (among other things):

```
T :: 'a set set and
objectsmap :: "'a set ⇒ ('a, 'm) Ring_scheme" and
restrictionsmap:: "('a set ×'a set) ⇒ ('a  ⇒ 'a)"
```

I then introduced the following:

```
definition  prestalk :: "'a  ⇒('a set × 'a) set" where
"prestalk x = { (U,s). (U ∈ T) ∧ x ∈U ∧ (s ∈ carrier (objectsmap U))}"


definition stalkrel :: "'a ⇒ ( ('a set × 'a) × ('a set × 'a) ) set" where
"stalkrel x = {( (U,s), (V,t) ). (U,s)  ∈ prestalk x ∧ (V,t)  ∈ prestalk x ∧ (∃W. W ⊆ U∩V ∧ x∈W ∧
 restrictionsmap (V,W) t = restrictionsmap (U,W)) s} "
```

I then proved that for each x, stalkrel x is an equivalence relation, and defined:

```
definition germ:: "'a ⇒  'a set ⇒ 'a ⇒ ('a set × 'a) set" where
"germ x U s = {(V,t). ((U,s),(V,t)) ∈ stalkrel x}"

definition stalk:: "'a ⇒( ('a set × 'a) set) set" where
"stalk x = {w. (∃ U s. w = germ x U s ∧ (U,s) ∈ prestalk x) }"
```

I'm trying to show that for each x this stalk x is a ring, and the ring operation is "built" out of the ring operations of rings `objectsmap (U∩V)` , i.e, I'd like `germ x U s + germ x V t` to be `germ x (U∩V) (restrictionsmap (U, (U∩V)) s + restrictionsmap (V, (U∩V)) t)`, where this last sum is the sum of ring `objectsmap (U∩V)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiplicative `Group` in the AFP entry mentioned is a record with four fields: a set `carrier` for the carrier, the binary group operation `top`, the inverse operation `iop` and the neutral element `one`. Similarly, a `Ring` is a record which extends an additive group (record `aGroup` with fields `carrier`, `pop`, `mop`, `zero`) with the binary multiplicative operation `tp` and the multiplicative unit `un`. If you want to define an instance of a group or record, you must define something of the appropriate record type. For example,

```
 definition my_ring :: "<el> Ring" where
   "my_ring = 
   (|carrier = <c>, 
     pop = <plus>, 
     mop = <minus>, 
     zero = <0>, 
     tp = <times>,
     un = <unit>|)"
```

where you have to replace all the `<...>` by the types and terms for your ring. That is, `<el>` is the type of the ring elements, `<c>` is the carrier set, etc. Note that you can specialise the type of ring elements as needed.

In order to prove that `my_ring` is indeed a ring, you must show that it satisfies the assumptions of the corresponding locale `Ring`:

```
lemma "Ring my_ring"
proof unfold_locales
  ...
qed
```

If you want to use the theorems that have been proven abstractly for arbitrary rings, you may want to interpret the locale using `interpretation`.

Comment: Brilliant, but I ran into a silly problem while trying to implementwhen defining my new ring operation in terms of another.. I thought just using control blocks would do the trick, but it gives an inner syntax error and fails to parse.

Comment: Here's what I tried: function stalk_pop :: " 'a ⇒ [('a set × 'a) set , ('a set × 'a) set]
 ⇒ ('a set × 'a) set  " where "stalk_pop x (germ x U s) (germ x V t) = germ x (U∩V) (  pop⇘objectsmap (U∩V)⇙ (restrictionsmap (U, U∩V) s)  
 (restrictionsmap (V, U∩V) t)  )" |
"stalk_pop x _ _ = undefined"   (to later try to prove is well-defined, I'd actually like to use the definition command, but it complains about the arguments on the LHS. Here germ is a previously defined constant and objectsmap takes 'a set to rings).

Comment: There's too little context to give an answer to your problem with `stalk_pop`. If `germ` is the constructor of a datatype, then try the function package (command `fun`) for defining `stalk_pop`. If `germ` is something else (in particular if it is a non-injective function), then you will have a hard time to define and work with `stalk_pop`. It's usually better generalise the definition of `stalk_pop` to arbitrary arguments and derive the given equation from it.

Comment: Indeed, germ was declared via a definition, being of type 'a ⇒  'a set ⇒ 'a ⇒ ('a set × 'a) set with germ x U s = {(V,t). ((U,s),(V,t)) ∈ stalkrel x}, where stalkrel x is a previously defined constant (germ x U s is supposed to be the equivalence class of (U,s) for the equivalence relation stalkrel x, and here x is just a parameter). In general, germ x does not have to be injective for each x. I'll try to amend the question to  clarify what I did an am attempting.

Comment: So you want to define functions over equivalence classes. Larry Paulson wrote a paper about how to do this in Isabelle: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Reports/equivclasses.pdf

As everything is happening inside a locale, you cannot use the more modern quotient packages, because you cannot define the type of equivalence classes.